# Begin of output container default value in a function

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, optional-parameters

I have function that has the following deceleration:

```
template<class Tinput_iterator, class Toutput_iterator>
int foo(const Tinput_iterator& begin_input, const Tinput_iterator& end_input, Toutput_iterator& begin_output);
```

The `begin` and `end` of the data container(`begin_input` & `end_input`) are mandatory. However, the `begin` of the output container(`end_input`) is optional.

What should I put instead of XXX in this case:

```
template<class Tinput_iterator, class Toutput_iterator>
int foo(const Tinput_iterator& begin_input, const Tinput_iterator& end_input, Toutput_iterator& begin_output = XXX);
```

**EDIT:**

if `begin_output` was passed like this for example:

```
std::vector<int> bar(data.size());
auto result=foo(begin(data),end(data),begin(bar));
```

`result` will contain an `integer`

`bar` will contain 100 values of `integers`.

if it was called like this:

```
auto result=foo(begin(data),end(data)/*,begin(bar)*/);
```

`result` will contain an `integer` (same as above)

of course there is no `bar` and nothing will be stored

Comment: I would think that depends on what `foo` does and how that default value should be used. Can you provide more details?

Comment: I very much doubt that pasing begin and end iterators by reference to const is a very good idea. I think passing them by value would be more appropriate, since you are going to make a copy of begin anyway.

Comment: @TartanLlama I have edited my question

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan it is just a habit to pass every thing using const&.. May you point me what is the problem here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most obvious solution to use the *default constructed* iterator as the *default value*.

```
template<class Tinput_iterator, class Toutput_iterator = void*>
int foo(Tinput_iterator begin_input, Tinput_iterator end_input, Toutput_iterator begin_output = {});
```

By the way, this all depends on how `Toutput_iterator` is defined. If the iterator is designed along the lines of Standard Library iterators, it would be fine. It would works with pointers too (the default value would be `nullptr`).

Notice that I've removed the reference from the declaration of `foo`'s arguments. That's because iterators are generally designed to be passed by value.

Comment: You have to specify the type of `Toutput_iterator` somewhere currently... :-/

Comment: @Jarod42 Sorry, I don't get it

Comment: with `foo(c.begin(), c.end())`, which is the type of `begin_output` (cannot be deduced).

Comment: @PaoloM I forgot to ask you, inside the body of the function how to check if the iterator was not passed and it is has a default value? thanks

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Just check it against `Toutput_iterator def_value{}`

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to overload `foo`:

```
template<class Tinput_iterator>
int foo(const Tinput_iterator& begin_input, 
        const Tinput_iterator& end_input) {}

template<class Tinput_iterator, class Toutput_iterator>
int foo(const Tinput_iterator& begin_input,
        const Tinput_iterator& end_input, Toutput_iterator& begin_output) {}
```

Comment: BTW, I think this is the way that is used in std algorithms (at least as my compiler implemented it). Do you think it is preferred for some reason ?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi This method is iterator implementation immune. For some iterators `it = {}` won't work.